# Make htaccess pass multiple variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables

What I'm trying to go for is subcategory/1/date so it passes subcat_id->1 sort->date. I am only able to get the first one though in PHP.

```
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+) subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)) subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1&sort=$2
```

Any idea where I went wrong in my code?

Comment: i see no difference with $3. I'm using echo $_GET['sort'];

Comment: Also consider adding $ to the end of the rules (or an OR between $ and literal ?), so that if the URL will match the second pattern, it won't match the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed my problem by switching the rules around and puting the "/" on the outside. Also added $ thanks to ctrahey.

```
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1&sort=$2
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+)$ subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1
```

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: you dont need the double brackets (( )) as $3 will be the same as $2

Comment: Also note that with just $, you will not match URLs with existing GET params (and currently you will not pass them if they are there).

Answer (score 2):

Try reversing the order, so if more parameters exist, it will get captured first

```
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1&sort=$2
RewriteRule ^subcategory/([0-9]+)$ subcategory.php?subcat_id=$1
```

Darn it got ahead of me!!